# jQuery Function is not called on image click - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, onclick

I am working on a MVC application and I have two image buttons and jQuery function for them but when I click on the image functions are not called

here is my chtml code:

```
@{
  int year = DateTime.Today.Year;
}

    <script>
        var year = '@year';
        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Holidays")'; 
        var updateHolidays = function() {
            $('#year').text(year);
            $('#details').load(url, { id: year });
        } 
        $('#previous').click(function() {
            year--;
            updateHolidays();
        });
        $('#next').click(function () {
            year++;
            updateHolidays();
        });
    </script>

    @if (Session["LoggedUserName"] != null)
    {
        <table>
            <tr style="height:10px">
                <td>
                    <h2>Holiday Calandar</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" id="previous" value="submit" src="~/Images/left-arrow.png" style="width:30px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h2>@year</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" id="next" value="submit" src="~/Images/right-arrow.png" style="width:30px"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Holiday", "Create", null, new { id = "lnkCreate" })</li>
                        </ul>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>
    }
```

and here is the controller code

```
public ActionResult Details(int year)
        {
            var model = db.tbl_HolidayList.Where(h => Convert.ToDateTime(h.Holiday_date).Year == year);
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

and this this detailview code

```
@model IEnumerable<OTESSystem.Models.tbl_HolidayList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>tbl_HolidayList</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Description")
            </th>
            <th>
                 @Html.Label("Date")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name, new { @class = "control", id = "" })
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description, new { @class = "control", id = "" })
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date, new { @class = "control", id = "" })
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkEdit" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkDelete" })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

    </table>
</fieldset>
```

can anyone tell me the mistake I am making ??

Comment: Start by not making year a string

Comment: your binding to the events before the dom element exists.

Comment: try putting the jQuert code in a document ready event?

Comment: mplungjan can you elaborate what you said?

Comment: I mean `var year = parseInt('@year',10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You javascript code runs before the page loads, so the events that you subscribe to do not yet exist. Apart from that your `year` variable is a string and not an integer, so you will get unexpected results when incrementing it.

First of all you need to make your `year` variable an integer value, you can do that using the `parseInt` function:

```
var year = parseInt('@year', 10);
```

(specifying the radix parameter will cover 2-digit year parsing as mentioned by [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan))

After that you either use a jQuery DOMContentLoaded event wrapper like this:

```
$(function() {

    var year = parseInt('@year',10);
    var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Holidays")'; 
    var updateHolidays = function() {
        $('#year').text(year);
        $('#details').load(url, { id: year });
    } 
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        year--;
        updateHolidays();
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        year++;
        updateHolidays();
    });

});
```

Or use `on` method when binding to events:

```
$('table').on('click', '#previous', function() {
   year--;
   updateHolidays();
});
$('table').on('click', '#next', function() {
   year++;
   updateHolidays();
});
```

Comment: AND make year an int in the JS too

Comment: @mplungjan yep, that's true

Comment: not window.load its a window.ready, load is not such a good idea

Comment: @Shiala there is not `window.ready` event, but there is a jQuery `$(document).ready` event, which uses DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: and in case year has two digits, use parseInt('@year',10)

Comment: I tried that with  $(document).ready(function (){ }); but nothing is happening on button click.

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui have you tried using `on` event? Do you have jquery referenced at all?

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui are you sure you have jquery referenced on the page and it's working correctly?